# Is it possible ignore unique constraint in insert and insert what doens't exist?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert many rows in a N:N relationship table, but if a key (IDTable1, IDTable2) exists, it will throw an exception and it doesn't insert the rest of the keys.

I am trying to insert the data in this way:

```
insert into MyTable(IDTable1, IDTable2)
VALUES(1,2),
VALUES(1,3),
VALUES(2,4),
VALUES(4,5),
VALUES(5,7);
```

The problema is that if for examaple (1,3) exists, the rest of the keys aren't inserted, but I would like that if a key exists ignore it and insert the keys that aren't exits.

Also I have tried with a try/catch, in this way:

```
begin try
insert into MyTable(IDTable1, IDTable2)
VALUES(1,2),
VALUES(1,3),
VALUES(2,4),
VALUES(4,5),
VALUES(5,7);
end try
begin catch
end catch
```

But the problem is the same, I get 0 rows affected.

is it possible to ignore the existing keys and insert the no existing keys?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `MERGE` or `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Or set `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` on the unique index.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, yes, `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` could also be used but I would personally avoid it. One would typically expect inserting to dup to raise a primary key violation rather than silently ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is with `MERGE`;

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
      IDTable1 int
    , IDTable2 int
    , CONSTRAINT UQ_MyTable UNIQUE (IDTable1, IDTable2)
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES(1,3);
GO

MERGE dbo.MyTable AS target
USING (
VALUES
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,4),
    (4,5),
    (5,7)
) AS source(IDTable1, IDTable2) ON 
    source.IDTable1 = target.IDTable1
    AND source.IDTable2 = target.IDTable2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (IDTable1, IDTable2) VALUES(source.IDTable1, source.IDTable2);
GO
```

This can also be done with `INSERT...SELECT` along with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (IDTable1, IDTable2)
SELECT IDTable1, IDTable2
FROM (
VALUES
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,4),
    (4,5),
    (5,7)
) AS source(IDTable1, IDTable2)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.MyTable as TARGET
    WHERE target.IDTable1 = source.IDTable1
    AND target.IDTable2 = source.IDTable2
    );
```

**EDIT:**

And here is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` method:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([IDTable1], [IDTable2])
SELECT source.[IDTable1], source.[IDTable2]
FROM MyTable AS target
LEFT JOIN (
VALUES
    (1,2),
    (1,3),
    (2,4),
    (4,5),
    (5,7)
) AS source(IDTable1, IDTable2) ON
     source.[IDTable1] = target.[IDTable1]
    AND source.[IDTable2] = target.[IDTable2]
WHERE target.[IDTable1] IS NULL;
GO
```

For this particular table, index, and data, `MERGE` appears to perform best based on fewest logical reads. The STATISTCS IO results for these 3 methods with SQL Server 2017 are:

MERGE:

```
Table 'MyTable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 22, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

NOT EXISTS:

```
Table 'MyTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 11, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
Table 'MyTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 17, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 11, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

I observed similar results with a `CLUSTERED` unique constraint.

However, I wouldn't generalize that `MERGE` is always the best approach from a performance perspective. SQL Server will ideally generate identical plans for semantically identical queries, although that doesn't always happen in practice. When performance is of particular concern, you need to examine the execution plans and test performance with representative data.

Comment: There are some difference between the two options? Perhaps in performance or something else?  Thanks so much.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, the queries are semantically identical. I updated my answer with performance details.

Comment: Use `MERGE` with caution though. It has better performance, but you need to check that you haven't had any of the known issues with it, and it's up to you whether that performance is worth the effort. `MERGE` had a few issues when it was first introduced, and it's not clear whether they have been fixed in 2016 or not, and you don't specify the version you are using. Usually I find that it's better to use a `LEFT JOIN` and not have to worry. Here's the issues for reference https://gavindraper.com/2017/05/08/usgin-sql-server-merge/

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you have to have the whole list ready to insert in one go, it doesn't try one, then move to the next.

This should do the trick for you. It's joining on the table you're inserting into, and ignoring anything that finds a match

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([IDTable1], [IDTable2])
SELECT [IDTable1], [IDTable2]
FROM [MySource] as source
    LEFT JOIN [MyTable] AS duplicates
        ON source.[IDTable1] = duplicates.[IDTable1]
             AND source.[IDTable2] = duplicates.[IDTable2]
WHERE duplicates.[IDTable1] IS NULL
```